# Can`t connect to PostgreSQL database in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: java, postgresql, pentaho, kettle

I`m trying to connect to my PostgreSQL database. What I create a connection and click the button "Test", I receive an error message. I can connect to this db via pgadmin without any problems, so it is not a connection or credentials issue

I`m using Pentaho kettle 8.3, Windows, java version "1.8.0_231"

```
Error connecting to database [Name] :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
Ошибка при попытке подсоединения.
```

Full error stack: https://pastebin.com/cLiB288e

Comment: Can you translate the error message coming from the driver? That is most likely to point at the cause.

Comment: @Cyrus It is not a very informative message: "Error while trying to connect."

Comment: On the first line it says "...database [Name]", is that really the name of the database or did you edit the real name out?

Comment: You can check this link. https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.3/Developer_center/Create_database_plugins

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "Name" is a name of connection in Database Connection wizard. I have replaced it with another name(like "DB") but nothing changed.

Comment: Is postgresql jdbc connector jar present in library folder?

Comment: @HelpingHand.. yes, I have postgresql-42.2.8.jar file in lib folder

Comment: Provided that you do run everything on the same machine (i. e. no port restrictions etc.) and have a compatible JDBC driver, I guess the problem might be hidden in your Kettle configuration. Share it maybe? Or you might also try to launch the Spoon in Java debug mode and debug the problematic part around `org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl` from your favorite Java IDE...

Comment: Where pgadmin is located? Same host  PID kettle is? PGAdmin is web server now might be located in different network with http access open only

Answer (score 0):

Try to add postgresql-42.1.1.jar in the /lib folder of PDI, restart the spoon and try again.

Comment: This states that driver is available "Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)"

Comment: Driver postgresql-42.2.8.jar is using, i sugested to change for older version of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

i faced 2 issues myself connecting to PostgreSQL few months back and following 2 things helped me

1.add postgres-42.1.1jar file in the 'lib' folder under PDI and restart the spoon.

2. if the normal JDBC connection convention does not work for you try below tip

while configuring the connection specify host name as follows 
{HOST IP}:{HOST PORT}/{instance name}?